# Image Segmentation in Python using regional method

Tags: python

I am attempting to implement image segmentation with the growing regions method for n-regions. In my code below, I have commented the different steps I am taking. Upon printing a few things, it seems as though I am not traversing the entire image and I can't figure out why. Is there anything obvious I am missing?

```
def neighbouring():
    return [[-1, -1], [0, -1], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [-1, 1], [-1, 0]]

def GrowingRegions(img, seeds, thresh):
    height, weight = img.shape
    neighbours = neighbouring()
    means = []
    regions = []
    seen = []
    for p in seeds: #for each point in the seeds
        #if p is already associated to a region, skip it
        for points in seen: 
            if np.array_equal(p, points):
                continue
                
        #create a new region r
        r = [p]
        #compute the mean 
        mean_r = img[p[0], p[1]]
        #create a list of neighbours for the point p
        n = [np.array((p[0] + neighbours[i][0], p[1] + neighbours[i][1])) for i in range(8)]
        
        #for each point in the neighbours 
        for point in n:
            (tempX, tempY) = point
            
            #check if you are within the image
            if tempX < 0 or tempY < 0 or tempX >= height or tempY >= weight:
                continue 
                
            #compute the gray level difference between the image at the point and the mean of the region
            gray_diff = abs(img[point[0]][point[1]] - mean_r)
            #check if the point is already associated to a region
            res = True
            for points in seen:
                if np.array_equal(point, points):
                    res = False
            
            #if it is not and the gray level difference is within threshold
            if res and (gray_diff < thresh):
                
                #we add the point to the region
                r.append(point)
                
                #we add it to the seen list as the point has been associated to the region
                seen.append(point)
                
                #we updated the neighhbours with the neighbours of the point
                neigh_p = [np.array((point[0] + neighbours[i][0], point[1] + neighbours[i][1])) for i in range(8)]
                n += neigh_p #add the neighbours of the point we just considered

                #update the mean
                mean_r = np.mean(r) #update the mean     
    
        regions.append(r) #add the final region to the regions list
    
    #here we want to associated each x,y to a label
    #the regions list to have [[points in region 1], [points in region 2], [points in region 3]...]
    
    #we take each point in region 1 (for example), and set its label to the mean of region 1 and so on 
    labels = np.zeros(img.shape)
    means = []
    for r in regions:
        mean = 0
        for i in range(len(r)):
            mean += img[r[i][0], r[i][1]]
        means.append(mean/len(r))
    
    for i,r in enumerate(regions):
        for points in r:
            x,y = points
            labels[x,y] = means[i] #set the label of x,y as the mean of the region
            
    return labels
```

**EDIT:**

I am using 10 seed points and each pixel value is normalised to be between 0 and 1, however I am still receiving a black image.

```
def neighbouring():
    return [[-1, -1], [0, -1], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [-1, 1], [-1, 0]]

def GrowingRegions(img, seeds, thresh):
    height, weight = img.shape
    neighbours = neighbouring()
    regions = []
    seen = []
    for p in seeds: 
        for points in seen: 
            if np.array_equal(p, points):
                continue
                
        r = [p]
        mean_r = img[p[0], p[1]]
        n = [np.array([p[0] + neighbours[i][0], p[1] + neighbours[i][1]]) for i in range(8)]
        new_n = n.copy()
        while len(new_n) > 0:
            for point in n:
                new_n.remove(point)
                (tempX, tempY) = point
                if tempX < 0 or tempY < 0 or tempX >= height or tempY >= weight:
                    continue 

                gray_diff = abs(img[point[0]][point[1]] - mean_r)

                res = True
                for points in seen:
                    if np.array_equal(point, points):
                        res = False

                if res and (gray_diff < thresh):

                    r.append(point)
                    seen.append(point)
                    neigh_p = [np.array((point[0] + neighbours[i][0], point[1] + neighbours[i][1])) for i in range(8)]
                    n.extend(neigh_p)
                    new_n.extend(neigh_p)
                    mean_r = np.mean(r) 
            n = new_n
        regions.append(r) 
    
    labels = np.zeros(img.shape)
    means = []
    for r in regions:
        mean = 0
        for i in range(len(r)):
            mean += img[r[i][0], r[i][1]]
        means.append(mean/len(r))
    
    for i,r in enumerate(regions):
        for points in r:
            x,y = points
            labels[x,y] = means[i] #set the label of x,y as the mean of the region
    return labels
```

Comment: Do your seed locations fully cover all regions of the image? You may need to use more seed locations

Comment: I tried with 10 seeds as well, but the final image is just black for me. I suspect because my loop doesn't loop through all the pixels, I don't actually "grow" my regions correctly.

Comment: Whenever you add it a neighboring point to a region, you need to add that to some queue. Then you need to continually go through that queue and for each neighboring point of the queued point, do the same thing, adding unassigned neighbors until the queue is finally empty. Right now, you don't use the neighbor points other than assigning them to the region.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I use my neighbours list n (to which I add the neighbours of the point I just added (neigh_p)) and am looping though it. Isn't this exactly the same as what you are suggesting?

Comment: No. You need a neighbors queue, where you pull one point from this list, and add all of its unassigned neighbors to the queue. Right now you loop once through the list n, which is the set of neighbors of p, which is one seed point. So you are stopping after visiting all of the seed point's neighbors.

Comment: Alright I see, but I was dynamically updating n but I suppose the updated n wasn't being taken into account I suppose.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, see answer